# How to copy bits of signal in FLOAT to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR representation and vice versa?

Tags: vhdl

I am currently using Floating-Point Megafunctions, which take input(s) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR and process the bits as FLOAT. Now I have a signal in FLOAT, how do I convert this FLOAT signal to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR with the same exact bits? Can I use to_slv function?

For example I have a signal in FLOAT (2 downto -3) => "011101", I want to have this signal with the same exact bits in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR representation (5 downto 0) => "011101", can I use to_slv?

And also the other way around, can I use to_float to copy the bits of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR to FLOAT representation with the same exact bits?

If it is not possible, then how can I do this?

Thank you!

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both std_logic_vector (package std_logic_1164) and float (package float_generic_pkg)  are single dimension arrays of element base type std_ulogic.

Type conversion should work.

Explicit type conversions are allowed between closely related types.

Array Types--Two array types are closely related if and only if

```
-- The types have the same dimensionality;

-- For each index position, the index types are either the same or are closely related; and

-- The element types are the same.
```

type STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_ULOGIC;

subtype STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is (resolved) STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR;

type UNRESOLVED_float is array (INTEGER range <>) of STD_ULOGIC;

subtype float is (resolved) UNRESOLVED_float;

For the indexes:

Abstract Numeric Types--Any abstract numeric type is closely related to any other abstract numeric type.

Dimensionality means the number of indices (elements) in the array.

EXCEPT - the 'caper' in the cake frosting:

In the case of conversions between numeric types, it is an error if the result of the conversion fails to satisfy a constraint imposed by the type mark.

The float type will have a left bound that's negative.

The way to deal with this is conversion functions that use a return value indexed to match the returned type and to_slv and to_float are supplied by package float_generic_pkg.  The to_float conversion function  has arguments for exponent width and fraction width with default values that are package generics.

(And it's always possible to read the packages design specifications.)

For some float:

```
 variable some_float:   float (2 downto -3) := ""011101";
 variable second_float: float (2 downto -3);
```

And a std_logic_vector of the same dimensionality:

```
 variable some_slv:   std_logic_vector( 5 downto 0);

 some_slv := to_slv(some_float);
```

If you've passed package generics for your float types fraction and exponent widths:

```
 second_float := to_float(some_slv);
```

If you have not:

```
 second_float := to_float(some_slv,2,3);
```

Where:

```
  function to_float (
    arg                     : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR;
    constant exponent_width : NATURAL := float_exponent_width;  -- length of FP output exponent
    constant fraction_width : NATURAL := float_fraction_width)  -- length of FP output fraction
    return UNRESOLVED_float;
```

The arguments exponent_width and fraction_width have default values passed as package generics that you can override.

You can read the 'source code'.  See [IEEE-SA Supplemental Material](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/), download the rather large zip file, uncompress it and in subdirectory ieee, the four files:

std_logic_1164.vhdl
std_logic_1164-body.vhdl
fixed_generic_pkg.vhdl
fixed_generic_pkg-body.vhdl

Comment: Dear David Koontz, thank you very much for your fast reply. However, I am not sure if I have understood your reply, probably because of my knowledge of VHDL.

So, if I have a floating signal A (2 downto -3) := "011101", then I write B <= to_slv(A), where signal B is in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0), will I get "011101" in signal B? Or, will to_slv get rid of the fraction bits (just like when we do to_integer(A)) and I will end up with different bits (not "011101") in B?

Sorry again if I didn't understand your previous answer well.

Comment: This is array type conversion and doesn't have anything to do with numerical types.  Note the dimensionality (number of indices, number of elements) is the same.  No information should be lost.  Read the functions design specification in package float_generic_pkg.

Comment: Dear David Koontz, thank you very much for your time and answer! I didn't know there are two different types of conversion, array and numerical, I just knew how to convert without knowing the differences between the two. This should solve my problem, for now, thank you again!