# VHDL procedure to extract sign, exponent, and mantissa from real type

Tags: vhdl

Need VHDL procedures to extract sign, exponent, and mantissa from real type?

```
bit  31 30    23 22                    0
     S  EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Here's what I'm doing in C code... how can I do this in VHDL with a real type?

```cpp
#include <math.h>                                                               
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
                                                                                
int main(void)                                                                  
{                                                                               
   double x, m;                                                                 
   int n;                                                                       
                                                                                
   x = 16.4;                                                                    
   m = frexp(x, &n);                                                            
                                                                                
   printf("The fraction is %lf and the exponent is %d\n", m, n);                
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
The mantissa is 0.512500 and the exponent is 5
```

Comment: See [help/on-topic]. "3. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  A real in any available VHDL implementation is an IEEE 64 bit floating point number whose value is indivisible in user space. Consider using -2008 package float_pkg which has a to_float for type real, note the mantissa of a 64 bit floating point value has more precision than type INTEGER.

Comment: did you have a look to [How to copy bits of signal in FLOAT to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR representation and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25177824/3972710)

Comment: The fixed/floating point packages in VHDL-2008 should have this.

Answer (score 1):

With VHDL things are divided into "synthetizable" and "non-synthetizable".

I did not understand at first that your question was about test bench (only)

So that there can not be a single answer to your question but it will be spliced in 2 parts:

First logic that can be synthesized:

```
...
elsif rising_edge(CLOCK) then
    M_OUT   <= F_IN(22 downto 0);
    EXP_OUT <= F_IN(30 downto 23);
    S_OUT   <= F_IN(31);
end if;
...
```

And then part of a test bench

```
...
vt: entity work.F_splitter
port map (  CLOCK   => clock,
        RESET_N => reset_n,
        F_IN    => f32test,
        M_OUT   => mant,
        EXP_OUT => expn,
        S_OUT   => sign_bit);
...

f32test <= to_slv(to_float(16.4));
...
```

I put a link to an example I wrote ( this may not be a fully acceptable VHDL, it is only a MCVE ) but it will allow you to play with it.

I leave you to display results in more friendly way

```
# EXECUTION:: NOTE   : Mantissa=00000110011001100110011
# EXECUTION:: NOTE   : Exponent=10000011
# EXECUTION:: NOTE   : SignBit='0'
```

Link to the MCVE:

[EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/gQiN)

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky way to find it....  this depends on image'real returning a floating point in standard format: x.yyye+/-zz... then, i parse the string to get the parts...

```vhdl
    procedure split_real(   
        real_in  :in  real
        fract1   :out integer;
        fract2   :out integer;
        exp      :out integer
    ) is
        variable c      :character;
        variable s      :string(1 to 20);
        variable l1     :line;      
        
        procedure line_new(
            variable  lout  : out line;
            constant  item  : in  string)
        is
        begin
            lout      := new string(item'range);
            lout.all  := item;      
        end procedure;      
    begin
        line_new(l1, real'image(real_in) );
    
        -- convert x.yyyE+zz => x yyy  zz
        -- convert x.yyyE-zz => x yyy -zz
        for i in l1.all'range loop
            c := l1.all(i);
            if ((c = 'e') or (c = 'E')) then
                l1.all(i) := ' ';
            
            elsif (c = '+') then
                l1.all(i) := ' ';
            
            elsif (c = '.') then
                l1.all(i) := ' ';
            end if;                                 
        end loop;

        --report "INTERNAL1:[" & real'image(real_in) & "]";
        --report "INTERNAL2:[" & l1.all & "]";

        read(l1, fract1);
        read(l1, fract2);
        read(l1, exp);
        
        report  " fract1:" & integer'image(fract1) 
              & " fract2:" & integer'image(fract2) 
              & " exp:" & integer'image(exp);
              
    end procedure;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 Potentially nonportable constructs "The use of the following constructs may lead to nonportable VHDL descriptions: ... — The use of explicit type conversion to convert floating-point values to integer values... — Models that depend on a particular format of T'IMAGE ..."

Answer (score 0):

```vhdl
   library ieee;
   use ieee.math_real.all;
   ...

    -- Function: split_real
    -- Purpose:  Split real into its floating point components
    procedure split_real(
        realnum  :in  real;
        
        sign     :out integer;
        mantissa :out real;
        exponent :out integer
    ) is
        variable rexponent :real;
        variable dividend  :real;
        variable quotient  :real;
    begin
        if (realnum < 0.0) then
            sign     := -1;
            dividend := -realnum;
        else 
            sign     := 1;
            dividend := realnum;
        end if;
        
        rexponent  := floor(log10(dividend));
        exponent   := integer(rexponent);
        quotient   := 10.0**rexponent;
        mantissa   := dividend / quotient;   
    end procedure;
```